# How do I customize the date-submit part in comment section?

Tags: 7, datetime

I am formatting the Date/Submit part of the comment. By default when we post any comment, it comes in the format of,
`Submitted by author-name on Sun, 06/12/2016 - 20:34`. I am using Adaptive theme.

I would like to change (1) date part in the `ago` format, like

`1 minute ago`

`24 minutes ago`

`an hour ago`

`2 hours ago`

`1 day ago`

`20 days ago`

`1 month ago`

`1 year ago`

`etc...`

AND the (2) Sentence part as described below,

**From** `Submitted by author-name on Sun, 06/12/2016 - 20:34` **To**
`author-name ------- ago`

**Now, Sentence part I did achieve as described below**,

1. I did some change in `comment.tpl.php` as shown below

**From->**

```
<?php if ($picture || $submitted): ?>
<footer<?php print $footer_attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $picture; ?>
  <p class="author-datetime"><?php print $submitted; ?></p>
</footer>
```

**To->**

```
<?php if ($picture || $submitted): ?>
<footer<?php print $footer_attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $picture; ?>
  <span class="auth"><?php print $author; ?></span>
  <div class="cret"><p><?php print $created; ?></p></div>
  <!--<p class="author-datetime"><?php print $submitted; ?></p>--> <!--I did remove this part, so it can not take the whole submitted by sentence by default-->
</footer>
```

So, by doing this, I can add `author-name` separately and `date` separately, so this will allow me to format the sentence the way I want

Hence now, I am getting,

`author-name Sun, 06/12/2016 - 20:34`

Now, how can I change the `date` part. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`format_interval()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7.x) to do this.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
  $variables['created'] = t('@created ago', array(
    '@created' => format_interval(REQUEST_TIME - $comment->created),
  ));
}
```

If you look at the source for [`template_preprocess_comment()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7.x), you are essentially just using `format_interval()` instead of `format_date()` to create the timestamps.  In the above, we run everything through [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x) so that the string "ago" gets translated properly.

Comment: Hi, this is working fine and very near to what I want. I am getting two parts in timestamp, e.g. `1 day 17 hours ago` or `15 hours 36 min ago`. Is it possible to just keep first part, like - `1 day ago` or `15 hours ago`?

Comment: @codenext Read the docs for `format_interval`.  The second parameter is the number of parts to display.

Comment: Yup man, I changed that part to `format_interval(REQUEST_TIME - $comment->created, 1)`, and it worked. Actually I read that one and was trying to do but was not sure where shall I put that and how? But now I knew, how this function working. These coding is very very new to me, so learning each steps by try and error. Thanks though, Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['date'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'l, d/m/Y');

  if (variable_get('node_submitted_' . $node->type, TRUE)) {
    $variables['display_submitted'] = TRUE;
    $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
    $variables['user_picture'] = theme_get_setting('toggle_node_user_picture') ? theme('user_picture', array('account' => $node)) : '';
  }
  else {
    $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
    $variables['submitted'] = '';
    $variables['user_picture'] = '';
  }
}

function mytheme_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  $variables['created']   = format_date($comment->created, 'custom', 'l, d/m/Y');
  $variables['changed']   = format_date($comment->changed, 'custom', 'l, d/m/Y');

  $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['author'], '!datetime' => $variables['created']));
}
?>
```

for more information check this link 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1075692

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this code is not changing much, It just removing the hh:mm part from the format. I did paste this in `template.php` and changed the mytheme with actual-name.